# How to integrate paypal to android app using webview

Tags: android, android-intent, paypal, paypal-nvp

I want to integrate paypal into my apps. I was close to getting there until i saw this : https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/support/faq#non-US-dev
Paypal does not allow non-US developer to use the REST API. So the choice that I am left with is the classic api. That is where the problem comes in. I do not know how to use them.

I am planning to use NVP api. I have no clue how to do it but below is my flow chart of the way I am planning to do. I need to set the item number, description, price, etc at checkout.java which will send to www.domain.com/setsessions.php

I am not sure if it will work though. But even if it can, then I wonder **how can the new 'intent' detect whether user has made payment successfully, fail payment or cancel payment.**

[image: App paypal flow]

I need help with this. It is really frustrating..have been trying to integrate paypal for almost 2 weeks. Feel so unproductive..

Is this even okay? Or is there a better method?
My requirement is to set the invoice no.,item no,description,price, location, all these are required from the app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MainActivity.java

```
public class PizzaMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        PayPal ppObj = PayPal.initWithAppID(this.getBaseContext(), "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_NONE);

        CheckoutButton launchPayPalButton = ppObj.getCheckoutButton(this, PayPal.BUTTON_152x33, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        launchPayPalButton.setLayoutParams(params);
        launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mRlayout1)).addView(launchPayPalButton);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
        char val[] = { '5', '0' };
        BigDecimal obj_0 = new BigDecimal(val);
        newPayment.setSubtotal(obj_0);
        newPayment.setCurrencyType("USD");
        newPayment.setRecipient("my@email.com");
        newPayment.setMerchantName("My Company");
        Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(newPayment, this);
        this.startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (resultCode) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
            // The payment succeeded
            String payKey = data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_PAY_KEY);
            // Tell the user their payment succeeded
            break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
            // The payment was canceled
            // Tell the user their payment was canceled
            break;
            case PayPalActivity.RESULT_FAILURE:
            // The payment failed -- we get the error from the EXTRA_ERROR_ID
            // and EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE
            String errorID = data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_ID);
            String errorMessage = data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE);
            // Tell the user their payment was failed.
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And give below permissions into your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

And add Activity into your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Add PayPal_MPL.jar Jar File as a Reference Library into your application

Comment: Do you know any way for enabling credit and debit card options , with paypal !

Comment: Has this been disabled for new integrations? 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/archive/mobile/ht_mpl-itemPayment-Android/