# How to link paypal for checkout in android

Tags: android, paypal

I have involved with a serious problem. I want to checkout via paypal in android. I saw this link [How to integrate paypal to android app using webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16578307/how-to-integrate-paypal-to-android-app-using-webview)  and run it. I found that paypal page opened but there is written "demo" in the left-bottom.  so i am confused should i used it for my real application?

if yes, What parameters should i need to pass? and how can i do it?

second I run to paypal sdk. and there is a sample demo. i run it and found that it login without internet.  Please any once help me how can i exact use it.

do there any exact source code?

Your help is my great help!

Thank you

Comment: Keep in mind that if your app is distributed from Google Play you must use Google Play's payment system. https://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy.html

Answer (score 0):

Jeff here from the PayPal Android SDK.  I'm not sure I fully understand your issue.  Are you using the [PayPal Android SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/)?  If so, please ensure you're following the readme during your integration.  Naturally, the SDK will allow login without internet in mock mode.